# how to call a google app script from google app engine for java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-apps-script

I have a google app script which I want to invoke from the Google App Engine for Java.  Can someone please guide on how to invoke such a script?

I tried to Google this and found only lots of information on how to do the reverse.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question 6 months ago. I could solve my problem using script timers.

But maybe this will work. I did not test it yet. You can publish an apps script as a service. That's part of working with the GUI. 
See f.i. this totorial : http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/articles/twitter_tutorial.html

My idea is that you make a request to this service from app engine with urlfetch. 
I did not test this, but I think it can work.

See als this post from Henrique :
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-script/thread?tid=3c339ede3f4e4afb&hl=en
Let me know if you solved your problem.

Comment: ok publishing as service part is clear. Now looking on UrlFetch part of invoking it from app engine.