# How to call GAS script from GAE (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, urlfetch

i've an Google Apps Script published as a service, access is set to any user of my domain, execution is set for owner user.
in this way it require user authentication when try direct access by url

now i wanna call that script from my google app engine project with python

i've read a lot and i've searched everywhere but not found a good solution

i've tryed urlfetch, httplib.HTTPSConnection and urllib2

my project is already authenticated with my apps domain using oauth and i've any  token ( accestoken, requesttoken and so on ).
i can work well with gdata api on google docs but i cannot call that script

how can i do?

thanks all
bye 
Sandro

Comment: If you are able to use your GAS service by entering the url in your browser, a urlfetch GET should also work. See also this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687317/how-to-call-a-google-app-script-from-google-app-engine-for-java

Comment: yes and no, it can work if i set that can be execute from everyone including anonymous users, if i set only for my domain i need authentication and authorization, i tryed with urlfetch but response is google login page. i already look at that pages

Comment: I think you have to try ClientLogin, because GAS does not support OAUTH : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034043/access-a-protected-google-apps-script-web-service-via-a-native-client-net-usi

Comment: i saw. for now i've granted anonymous access to that script and i use a post parameter as app secret. is not secure but not insecure too.
I will try to implement ClientLogin" in early future, for now i spent to much time on this problem. i'm sure that gdata actually not have an client for gas, but i suppose using GDrive Api i can find a good way to do it